# Как в bat-нике запустить консольное приложение так, чтобы окно этого консольного приложения после исполнения не закрывалось?

Tags: java, bat

Запускаю в `bat`-нике консольное приложение:

```
start java -jar app.jar
```

открывается новое консольное окно, приложение выполняется, окно закрывается.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы оно не закрывалось, чтобы видеть то, что приложение выводило в консоль?
В конце кода приложения можно конечно вставить *"нажмите клавишу для продолжения"*, но оно может завершиться и множеством всяких исключений

Comment: Можно запускать без start.

Comment: действительно  .

Comment: в батнике на новой строке добавить "pause"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, запускать без `start`, тогда отдельное окно консоли создаваться не будет, а в bat-файле если нужно прописать `pause`.

```
java -jar app.jar
pause
```

Без `start` следующая команда bat файла не будет выполняться, пока не выполнится текущая.

Также можно запустить так, что дополнительное окно консоли не закроется автоматически, а останется открытым с "приглашением ввода" cmd:

```
start cmd /k java -jar app.jar
```

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Можно заставить программу что-то считывать бесконечно с консоли

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = console.nextInt();
```

Тогда консоль будет ждать считки значения, в случае, когда вы что-то введете она завершится.